# Proper phrasing of (anti)(animal cruelty) to avoid ambiguity

Tags: grammar, ambiguity

I came across this tweet, and found the construction a bit funny.

> Liberal MP Nathaniel Erskine-Smith is up on a motion to amend his omnibus anti-animal cruelty bill.

On first read, I parsed it as an omnibus, anti-animal, cruelty bill, which is obviously not the intent.

What's the proper way to write this to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: Maybe "Liberal MP Nathaniel Erskine-Smith is up on a motion to amend his omnibus bill opposing animal cruelty."

Comment: Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/37/

Comment: There's always a relevant xkcd.

Comment: If you like subtlety, you can employ the technique recommended by the Chicago Manual of Style and use en dashes instead of hyphens to connect compound words whose individual components are themselves compound; i.e., _anti–animal cruelty bill_ or _anti–animal-cruelty bill_. That is in theory unambiguous, but unfortunately, the vast majority of readers are highly unlikely to notice this difference (much less know about it in the first place), so it probably wouldn’t get you very far in the real world.

Comment: @James I think your suggestion, to rewrite it to separate the words which might otherwise be mistakenly linked, is the only sensible approach.  Rearranging punctuation might help the reader but it won't help the listener.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Just one person's perspective: if I saw "anti–animal cruelty bill" I would notice it but I would not understand the intent. (Well, I would be able to figure out the meaning from the context, but I would consider it to be even more unclear than "anti-animal cruelty bill.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your reading of the phrase. It is a bit funny, in the sense of humorous. A great example of a sentence that says the *opposite* of what is intended.

The following seem unambiguous:

> anti-animal-cruelty bill
>
> animal anti-cruelty bill

Or one could reword as suggested by @KevinWorkman.